# Stop countdown time

Tags: javascript

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    count: 20
  };
}

const {count} = this.state

componentDidMount (){
    const {startCount} = this.props
    this.setState({
        count: startCount
    })
    this.doIntervalChange()
}

componentDidMount (){
    this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            count: prevState.count - 1   
        }))
    },1000)
}

componentWillMount (){
    clearInterval(this.myInterval)
}
```

Comment: What should I do to stop time at 0?

Comment: Use an if statement?

Comment: Why do you have two “componentDidMount” methods?

Comment: use clearInterval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Answer (score 2):

Try this (untested):

```
this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const newCount = prevState.count - 1;
        if (newCount == 0) {
            clearInterval(this.myInterval);
        }
        return { count: newCount };
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I would like to ask a little more. If wanting to skip to the next page, what should I do?

Comment: @FewConnectF've You're welcome. What do you mean "next page"? You haven't explained what your app is. Can you explain your views? Maybe add some screenshots too.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor (props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        count: 20 
        }
    }


render() {
    const {count} = this.state
    return (
        <div>
            <Container className="comming">
            <Form className="boxrandomtest">
                    <h1 className="textrandomtest">แบบทดสอบวัดระดับ</h1> <h1 className="cdtimer"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="clock" /> {count}</h1>
                    <Form className="Q1">
                       <h3>1. เวลาใดที่กินเวลาน้อยที่สุด</h3>  <br></br>
                       <Button className="rdTest1" href='/randomtest2'><h5>ก.อดีต</h5></Button><br></br>
                       <Button className="rdTest1" href='/randomtest13'><h5>ข.ปัจจุบัน</h5></Button><br></br>
                       <Button className="rdTest1" href='/randomtest2'><h5>ค.อนาคต</h5></Button><br></br>

                    </Form>
                    <Button className="rdTestbt1" href='/randomtest1'><h5>รีหน้าเดิม</h5></Button>
                    <Button className="rdTestbt2" href='/randomtest2'><h5>ข้อต่อไป</h5></Button>
            </Form>
            </Container>
        </div> 
    )
}

componentDidMount (){
    const {startCount} = this.props
    this.setState({
        count: startCount
    })
    this.doIntervalChange()
}

componentDidMount (){
    this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const newCount = prevState.count - 1;
            if (newCount == 0) {
                clearInterval(this.myInterval);
            }
            return { count: newCount };
        });
    }, 1000);
}

componentWillMount (){
    clearInterval(this.myInterval)
}
```

}

Comment: I just learned to write apps for the first time. This is, therefore, an important lesson for me.